# How to hide/unhide columns added at the borders of the range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a macro which will hide/unhide a specified range of columns. 
Adding a column within the named range isn't problematic, but when adding a column at the borders of this range - macro doesn't work. For example, AM:BF is the named range ("Furniture") in my sheet. I need to add a column BG which will also be hidden by the macro. Same story when adding a new column on the left border. Could you guide me how to improve the code so that the columns added at the borders of the range will also be hidden/unhidden?

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Furniture").EntireColumn
.Hidden = Not .Hidden   
End With
```

Comment: You need to resize the named range when you are adding columns to borders.

Comment: Is the left border always the same column?

Answer (score 0):

I've added a variable `RangeName` (of type `String`) that equals to the name of the Name Range = "Furniture".

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub DynamicNamedRanges()

Dim WBName As Name
Dim RangeName As String
Dim FurnitureNameRange As Name
Dim Col As Object
Dim i As Long

RangeName = "Furniture" ' <-- a String representing the name of the "Named Range"

' loop through all Names in Workbook    
For Each WBName In ThisWorkbook.Names
    If WBName.Name Like RangeName Then '<-- search for name "Furniture"
        Set FurnitureNameRange = WBName
        Exit For
    End If
Next WBName

' adding a column to the right of the named range (Column BG)
If Not FurnitureNameRange Is Nothing Then '<-- verify that the Name range "Furnitue" was found in workbook
    FurnitureNameRange.RefersTo = FurnitureNameRange.RefersToRange.Resize(Range(RangeName).Rows.Count, Range(RangeName).Columns.Count + 1)
End If

' loop through all columns of Named Range and Hide/Unhide them
For i = 1 To FurnitureNameRange.RefersToRange.Columns.Count
    With FurnitureNameRange.RefersToRange.Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(1, i)).EntireColumn
        .Hidden = Not .Hidden
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

place the following in your worksheet code pane:

```
Option Explicit

Dim FurnitureNameRange As Name
Dim adjacentRng As Range
Dim colOffset As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim newRng As Range

    If colOffset = 1 Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo ExitSub
    Set adjacentRng = Range(adjacentRng.Address)

    With ActiveSheet.Names
        With .Item("Furniture")
            Set newRng = .RefersToRange
            .Delete
        End With
        .Add Name:="Furniture", RefersTo:="=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & newRng.Offset(, colOffset).Resize(, newRng.Columns.Count + 1).Address
    End With

ExitSub:
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set FurnitureNameRange = ActiveSheet.Names("Furniture") 'ThisWorkbook.Names("Furniture")
    On Error GoTo 0

    colOffset = 1
    Set adjacentRng = Nothing
    If FurnitureNameRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set adjacentRng = Target.EntireColumn
    With FurnitureNameRange.RefersToRange
        Select Case Target.EntireColumn.Column
            Case .Columns(1).Column - 1
                colOffset = -1
            Case .Columns(.Columns.Count).Column + 1
                colOffset = 0
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```