# Adding a column to a named range based on a cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a macro which will be adding a column to a named range provided on the value in a column next to a named range.

To be more specific, the range B:G is named "Furniture". Depending on the value in the first row of a column next to this range (A or H), I need to add a column to this named range. So if a cell H1 is "Furniture" then column H will be added to the named range "Furniture".

Of course, it has to be a universal method so that every column named "Furniture" next to this range will be added to it.

I'm a complete newbie to VBA, so I created a code attached below for a singular case. However, it doesn't work and, moreover, it's not a general code.

```
Range("H1").Select
If cell.Value = "Furniture" Then
With Range("Furniture")
.Resize(.Columns.Count + 1).Name = "Furniture"
End With
End If
```

Comment: Find the time to give feedback and mark as "ANSWERS" for previous posts you asked here (before posting a new one). See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998777/how-to-hide-unhide-columns-added-at-the-borders-of-the-range , and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981782/macro-to-hide-unhide-columns-in-excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could provide more information about the structure of your sheet, I could help you with a decent loop, because it's not clear how you want to loop through the columns / rows. Can the target range always be found in the first row of every  column?

For now, this will help you hopefully, as it dynamically adds columns to a range. The name of the particular range comes from the selected cell.

```
lastColumn = Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column


For currentColumn = 1 To lastColumn

    Cells(1, currentColumn).Activate

    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then

        targetRange = ActiveCell.Value

        ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Select

        On Error Resume Next

        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=targetRange, RefersTo:=Range(targetRange & "," & Selection.Address)

        If Err <> 0 Then

            Debug.Print "Identified range does not exists: " & targetRange

        Else

            Debug.Print "Identified range found, extended it with " & Selection.Address

        End If

    End If

Next currentColumn
```

Comment: This is even further than the proposed code from what was asked... You are creating a new named range and the OP just want to extend it...

Comment: Simply I need to add a column to a named range if the value in the first row is "Furniture". There are no gaps between these columns - I mean that range B:G is named "Furniture" and H column should be added to this range (subsequently I, J, K, etc. if there's proper value in a column, not I, K, M, or something like that).

Comment: @R3uK You are almost right; but I didn't know that, too: Instead of creating a new range, Excel will throw an error - fixed that with the new revision. There is still one major drawback: Running the script several times will add the same column again and again. This would require an additional check / comparison of the "column to be added" and the "column already existing"